# Getting 'Permission Denied' when running bundler command

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, ruby

I need to install bundler for an application so here's what I'm doing (instructions from the application documentation directly):

1. `mkdir ~/.gems`
2. `export GEM_HOME=~/.gems`
3. `gem install bundler -v 1.10.3`

After doing these three instructions, I run `bundler -v` and get the following exception:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: Permission denied`

It works fine if I run it as sudo. I also understand it's a permissions issue because root is the user and group on the folder. I guess the question is how can I install bundler without using the `/usr/local` folder so that I have access to it without using root?

**[EDIT]**

When I run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/bundle` I see the following:

```
-rwx------ 1 root root 495
```

When I run `ls ld ~/.gems` I see the following:

```
drwx------ 10 gflouis1 domain users 143 /home/gflouis1/.gems
```

FYI: gflouis1 is my username

Comment: Did you run `mkdir ~/.gems` as root also (e.g. using `sudo`)?

Comment: I actually don't remember. If not, could that be a reason as to why I'm getting this exception? I'm pretty sure I didn't though since it was in the documentation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/bundle` and `ls -ld ~/.gems`

Comment: Edits have been made.

Comment: What if you do `gem install bundler -v 1.10.3 --user-install`?

Answer (score 1):

Without `sudo` you don't have the necessary permissions, so add the executable bit for the group and others:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change root permissions by:

```
sudo chown root:user(yourusername) filename
```